# Vue Cli 3 Generated Project Set HTML Title

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

Currently, after generating a project with Vue CLI 3 the title is "Vue App".

If I set the title in the created hook via **document.title** the browser will still will flash "Vue App" prior to displaying the title set via document.title.

Looking for a way to set the HTML title for a Vue CLI 3 generated project without it flashing the default "Vue App" title first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the title in `/public/index.html` statically.

Setting it to an empty string in index.html and keeping the update in the hook gets rid of the flashing.

Comment: Would much rather prefer to load dynamically

Comment: Setting the title to empty in public/index.html did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @xspydr Well, you still set the title dynamically, but start with an empty default value for the title instead of a wrong one.

Comment: In my newly created Vue CLI 4 app, there was no "/public/index.html" so I had to create one: `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="us"><head><title>My Title</title></head><body><div id="app"></div></body></html>`

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, I had deleted default `index.html` for some reason and needed the default content again. You can get it from `\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\index-default.html`. It has got pretty much exactly what @zett42 has shown in the comment above.

Comment: My problem was that the `index.html` file was at the root of my project.  Once I moved it into my `public` directory, the Vue CLI picked up my changes to the `<title>`

Answer (score 2):

also You can use custom index.html in another way, modify your vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin("html")
      .tap(args => {
        args[0].template = './public/index.html'
        return args
      })
  }
};
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because changing the title based on the project (settings) makes more sense than hard-coding it in the actual file

Answer (score 0):

You can add `postinstall` to `scripts` section in your `package.json` with next command:
`"postinstall": "cp ./public/index.html ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/index-default.html"`